# Where can I find 'no limits' Texas Hold'em game logs?

Tags: poker-texas-holdem, computer-ai

I've been looking at some papers about developing AI players for Texas Hold'em, and many of them have used betting history from expert human players as training data.  I have so far been unable to find a paper that referenced where they got that betting history.

**Where can I find betting history for 'no limits' Texas Hold'em games?**

I imagine the game history will be in the format of a log file containing the number of chips each player has, the cards dealt to each player, and all the bets made.

---

Here is an example of a paper I looked at:

[Decision Generalisation from Game Logs in No Limit Texas Hold’em](http://ijcai.org/papers13/Papers/IJCAI13-457.pdf)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Building a Poker Playing Agent based on Game Logs using Supervised Learning](http://repositorio-aberto.up.pt/bitstream/10216/59566/1/000143811.pdf)

I found this paper on creating a Hold'em AI that refers to two external log files on page 100 of that paper. One no longer exists. The other, from [hhsmithy](https://www.hhsmithy.com/), costs a couple bucks. They offer logs from various sources, including Poker Stars, Full Tilt Poker and Party Poker.

They also offer a smaller, free set that you can use to build your setup.